# How do I change the timezone of Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have been googling but there seems no adequate answers, I assume Selenium grabs it from my computer, but I should be able to feed it something else no?

Comment: How is this unclear?

Comment: You can provide the code that you have tried , error trace if any. Then user might vote for reopening this question.

Answer (score 1):

The browser date/time functions are all JavaScript. You should be able to use Sinon.JS or TimeShift.JS to mock the date/time: 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/faking-system-time-date-with-selenium-webdriver
or
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11513/what-is-the-best-way-to-mock-browser-time-and-time-zone-in-selenium

Comment: it seems you forgot to add a link to the original answer you've pasted even without formatting 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/faking-system-time-date-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I am able to run the code, however my timezone does not change for this.